# How to copy a file from the repository, into the Docker container used for a job, in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

How can I add a file from my project into a Docker using in a `gitlab-ci` job. Suppose I have below job in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` .

```
build:master:
  image: ubuntu:latest
  script:
    - cp sample.txt /sample.txt
  stage: build
  only:
    - master
```

How to copy a sample.txt inside Ubuntu image? I was thinking as it is already a running container so we can't perform copy command directly but have to run

```
docker cp sample.txt mycontainerID:/sample.txt
```

but again how will I get mycontainerID? because it will be running inside a Gitlab runner and any random id will be assigned for every run. Is my assumption is wrong?

Comment: You could create a git repository for build/test/general helper flies (which ever need you have) and clone it as the first stage of your scirpt. I also believe this will yield a better reproducible results

Answer (score 30):

The file is already inside the container. If you read carefully through the CI/CD build log, you will see at the very top after pulling the image and starting it, your repository is cloned into the running container.

You can find it under `/builds/<organization>/<repository>`

*(note that these are examples, and you have to adjust to your actual organization and repository name)*

Or with the variable `$CI_PROJECT_DIR`

In fact, that is the directory *you* are in when starting the job.

For example, this .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: alpine

test:
  script:
    - echo "the project directory is - $CI_PROJECT_DIR"
    - cat $CI_PROJECT_DIR/README.md ; echo
    - echo "and where am I? - $PWD"
```

returns this pipeline output:
[image]
As you can see, I could print out the content of the README.md, inside the container.

Comment: what if I need e.g. configuration stored in same gitlab server but different repository? is it possible somehow? I suppose no...
there is import keyword, however it is pure for importing to .gitlab-ci.yml file itself, I think

Answer (score 0):

I use 'scp' to copy files from my gitlab repository to my server (not in container).

for example :

```
  deploy:
    script:
      - scp -i $ID_RSA_FRONT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no example.txt $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_IP_FRONT:/tmp/example.txt
      ...
```

Here the file example.txt is in the root of my gitlab repository.

Answer (score -2):

We **do not need to copy**. The repository files will be **available** in the image. GitLab does that for us.

Type to use `ls(linux) or dir(windows)` command depending your platform to list files and folders.

Comment: Not all files in the repo will be available in the image. For image, the file .gitlab-ci.yaml is not available in the image.

Answer (score -4):

Your runner is already executing `script` in your docker container.
What your job does here is:

- start a container using Ubuntu image and mount your Git project in
  there.
- cp sample.txt from Git project's root to container's
- stop the container saying "job done"

That's basically what `image` means: use this docker image to start a container that will execute the commands listed in the script part.

I don't exactly understand what you're trying to achieve. If it's a build job, then why don't you actually COPY your file from your Dockerfile and configure your job to build it with `docker build` ? A Runner shell executor doing `docker build -t your/image:latest -f build/Dockerfile .` will do just fine. Then you push this image in some Docker registry (Gitlab's for example, or Docker Hub).

If really your goal is more complex and you want to just add a file to a running container, you can use the same Runner (with a shell executor, not a docker one, so no `image`) and run something like

```
- docker run --name YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME -v $PWD:/mnt ubuntu:latest cp /mnt/sample.txt /sample.txt
- docker commit -m "Commit Message" -a "You" YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME your/image:latest
- docker push your/image:latest
- docker rm YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME
```

Note: I'm not 100% sure the first one would work, but that would be the general idea of creating an image from a container without relying on the actual Dockerfile if **really** you can't achieve your goal with a Dockerfile.