# how does gitlab ci clone repo into docker?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm familar with Bamboo but new to gitlab ci, I have tried several times with gitlab and found a key advantage of gitlab is the **automatic cloning of git repository**.

The tricky part is gitlab ci can even clone repository **into docker container automatically**.

my git repo:

```
.git    
.gitlab-ci.yml
foobar.sh
```

this job:

```
  job1:
  stage: run
  image: 
    name: my_image
  script: 
    - ./foobar.sh
    - some other scripts within the docker
```

can successfully run.

The log shows after pulling my_image, there's a git clone action, like what another SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52679245/how-to-copy-a-file-from-the-repository-into-the-docker-container-used-for-a-job/54188996#54188996) said. but the log isn't detail enough to let me know where this command is triggered(I'm not the owner of gitlab ci runner so cannot control the log verbose level, if it matters).

So my questions:

1. Is this `git clone` command run within or outside the docker?
2. If within, who triggered it? what's the complete command of docker run ...?
3. If outside, when and where is the directory mounted to docker?

   I have read the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#git-strategy), but didn't find anywhere to explain above mechanism.

Comment: it is done by the helper image described here [helper_image](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#helper-image), I assume that this image is mounting the build path in the target container, how this is done I did not found out at the moment.