# How to mount/copy folder from the git repo to a service container?

Tags: docker, gitlab, mount, docker-container, volumes

I am trying to copy (or should l say mount) a folder and a file from my git repo to a service container in my gitlab-ci.yml file. I dont know how to do it. thats how l want to map it:

```
volumes:
      - ./myfolder-templates:/templates
      - ./config/mysecondfolder/file.properties:/opt/classes/file.properties
```

my gitlab-ci.yml file looks like this:

```
 image: openjdk:11

 build-job:
  services: 
    - name: artifactory.mycompany.com/oracleimage
      alias: test_db
    - name: docker-releases.mycompany.com/anotherimage
      alias: test_other
```

now, i want to add the above mentioned file and folder to the container whose alias is `test_other`. How should l go about it? I found many gitlab forum threads. but they all talk about configuring the runner for mounting files. I dont wanna do that. Also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52679245/how-to-copy-a-file-from-the-repository-into-the-docker-container-used-for-a-job). It doesn't answer my question. Is there a way to do that in the yml file? btw. I'm using a shared runner and cant configure it, in case that is relevant.

Comment: why don't you just clone the original repo into the container?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer, that's not an option, these are dynamic files, that need to be mapped onto the image during the CI build.

Comment: OK, it turns out, you CANNOT  mount files or folders inside the gitlab-ci.yml file to a service image.  Instead I had to write a shell script in my root that copies the necessary files to the service  image  and run it in the respective job of the pipeline.